# how to count particular values from same column in mysql

Tags: count

i have two tables namely 1.caccount and 2.upload. 1.caccount is use for register users. 2.upload is use for post a job when user is logged in. i put columnname `uid` in both tables at beginning.that will use to show only jobs that posted by particular user. now i want to display number of jobs posted by particular user? how to count that particular user is posting a this amount of job? sorry for my bad english. thanks in advance.

---

this is a screenshot for caccount table
 [this is a screenshot for upload table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTiel.jpg)
 [this is a main page where i have to display count of positions offer by    particular user or company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGNF6.jpg)

Comment: Please include your tables directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select count(*)
from upload
where uid = <the user id>;
```

Comment: its not working.Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/adnacjobs/adnacjobs.com/companies.php on line 195
open positions gives this error